# How to refresh token after expiry in django knox authentication?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox

I am running django application with django knox token authentication. I was able to do login with the package.

But after the token expired, url response are throwing " Invalid Token".

I don't understand how to refresh the token after expiry? whether i need to login again? if it is, the user will get irritated.

How to do it in proper way?

Which is the best token authentication for django rest framework?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is:

```
#setting.py

REST_KNOX = {
   'TOKEN_TTL': timedelta(hours=10), #time to live (without refresh)
   'TOKEN_LIMIT_PER_USER': None,
   'AUTO_REFRESH': True,
   'MIN_REFRESH_INTERVAL': 60 #number of seconds
}
```

You can of course change the settings. If you don't specify the `'MIN_REFRESH_INTERVAL'` it doesn't work.
The advantage of knox IMOP is that the token refresh is done automatically, and you don't have to do it yourself (unlike JWT, where you need to specifically ask for a new token with the refresh token).
It's less secure than JWT. But the plus is that you have less work to do on the client side.